# Extract references/Compile a single function in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, automation

I recently got into the situation where i had access to a huge code base, which i couldn't build and i needed to test couple of its functions.
Nevertheless, those functions had references of functions/variables found in other files so it is a big mess trying to extract them manually.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

For example, i want to test function `foo` in test.c but `foo` depends on `bar` function found in file test2.c. The `bar` function could then be dependent on `booz` which is found in test3.c.

So in the case above, one could gather `foo`, `bar`, and `booz` in one file and compile.

Answer (score 0):

To generate cross references you can use Doxygen.

You can have a look for PostgreSQL C source code [here](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/) and search for example definition of `main` function.

Comment: interesting, thanks. The documentation looks pretty descriptive and includes all references, but someone would still have to go through them manually and resolve them. Do you know if possible to automate this procedure somehow? I am more interested in compiling the function at the end

Comment: I don't know. I'm only an Doxygen end user.